# How to correct this code to place the points on the right part of the map?

Tags: python, scatter-plot, matplotlib-basemap

I want to plot a scatter over a basemap, my code is this:
%matplotlib inline
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

## create figure and axes

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))

m = Basemap(projection='lcc', resolution='h', \
    lat_0=51.53, lon_0=0.08,
    width=1E6, height=1.2E6)
m.shadedrelief()
m.drawcoastlines(color='gray')
m.drawcountries(color='gray')


y,x = m(dfrt['lon'].values, dfrt['lat'].values)
m.scatter(x,y, marker="o", color='g', alpha=0.7, zorder=5)

plt.title("Localización de los Bikepoints")
plt.show()
```

dfrt is this dataframe:

```
commonName  id  lat lon placeType   url additionalProperties2   category    key sourceSystemKey value   modified
0   River Street , Clerkenwell  BikePoints_1    51.529163   -0.109970   BikePoint   /Place/BikePoints_1 {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Addit...   Description TerminalName    BikePoints  001023  2019-08-22T11:17:04.327Z
1   Phillimore Gardens, Kensington  BikePoints_2    51.499606   -0.197574   BikePoint   /Place/BikePoints_2 {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Addit...   Description TerminalName    BikePoints  001018  2019-08-22T11:10:02.34Z
2   Christopher Street, Liverpool Street    BikePoints_3    51.521283   -0.084605   BikePoint   /Place/BikePoints_3 {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Addit...   Description TerminalName    BikePoints  001012  2019-08-22T11:12:02.7Z
3   St. Chad's Street, King's Cross BikePoints_4    51.530059   -0.120973   BikePoint   /Place/BikePoints_4 {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Addit...   Description TerminalName    BikePoints  001013  2019-08-22T11:08:02.047Z
4   Sedding Street, Sloane Square   BikePoints_5    51.493130   -0.156876   BikePoint   /Place/BikePoints_5 {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Addit...   Description TerminalName    BikePoints  003420  2019-08-22T11:14:02.787Z
```

But the plot I get is not correct, the green points should be in London:

[image: Wrong map]

Any thoughts? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
y,x = m(dfrt['lon'].values, dfrt['lat'].values)
```

which should read:

```
x,y = m(dfrt['lon'].values, dfrt['lat'].values)
```

as per Matplotlib documentation:
[matplotlib basemap](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/mapcoords.html)

Here's the result you expected:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Artur, please one question more, how to zoom the area to see each plot better?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your x and y are reversed. Try changing

```
y,x = m(dfrt['lon'].values, dfrt['lat'].values)
```

to

```
x,y = m(dfrt['lon'].values, dfrt['lat'].values)
```